# Why is this a homomorphism (proof of no simple groups order 144)

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a goup of order 144.

Roughly at 10:50 for [No simple groups of order 66 or 144. - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8AzVj_hocQ), he defines the homomorphism:

$$\psi : G \rightarrow S_4, \psi (g) = \sigma \in S_4 \text{ where $\sigma (i) = j$ if } g^{- 1} P_i g = P_j$$

Now why is this a homomorphism?

I suppose that $\psi (g) = \sigma_1, \psi (h) = \sigma_2$. Then $(g h)^{- 1} P_i (g h) =
h^{- 1} (g^{- 1} P_i g) h = h^{- 1} P_{\sigma_1 (i)} h = P_{(\sigma_2 \cdot
\sigma_1) (i)}$. So $\psi (g h) = \sigma_2 \cdot \sigma_1$. But I need $\psi (g h) = \sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2$ for this to be a homomorphism?

What mistake did I make here?

Comment: The permutations are being composed left-to-right; so $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ means “do $\sigma_1$ first, then do $\sigma_2$”. It’s not an uncommon way to compose permutations.

Comment: Then, instead define $\sigma(i)=j$ if $gP_ig^{-1}=P_j$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Ok I'll try that out see if it works with the rest of his video.